# Stripe Webhooks: check if object changed

Tags: stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe webhooks in a webapp to implement subscriptions using Stripe Billing. The webapp has a frontend and backend.

When a subscription is started or canceled the frontend directly communicates with the backend and everything happens by synchronously calling the Stripe API.

For example, to cancel a subscription, this is the flow:

- the user taps on a button in the frontend
- frontend calls my app backend to cancel the sub
- backend calls the stripe api to actually cancel the sub
- backend updates the saved subscription object in its own db

Here comes the "problem": after some seconds a `customer.subscription.deleted` webhook calls comes at my backend telling me to update the subscription I just saved. **I want to avoid the double-save for performance reasons and was wondering if these stripe objects have some kind of signature or update count to check if they have changed with respect to the previous version**.

I think it's quite common to use webhooks only for out-of-band updates, so this use case should be supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an "update" count or signature for each state of a Subscription. One alternative might be to skip updating your Subscription object in the database directly when processing the request from your own front end to your backend. Instead you could depend primarily on the event notification from Stripe to update your database. This way, you're only updating the database once and if you need to make changes directly from the Stripe dashboard for some reason, those will still propagate to your backend.

I also wanted to note that you should build your webhook event handler to be idempotent by checking the ID of the event before processing as occasionally Stripe will send the same event more than once even if acknowledged successfully.

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-handling